# ShrinkWrap to multiple objects

Tags: mesh, shrinkwrap

Is there a way to Shrinkwrap and move a plane across more than one mesh?

Answer (score 8):

You can remake a shrinkwrap modifier in geometry nodes and reference a collection as a target:

[image]

Here, I'm telling the mesh's vertices to acquire the position of the nearest point (on a face) of any geometry in collection 1.  That's just like a shrinkwrap on nearest surface point, except I'm referencing multiple objects.

Other kinds of shrinkwrap can be recreated as well; a raycast node can be used for project-mode shrinkwraps, as well as to make determinations like inside/outside.

Note that shrinkwraps don't always end up working like you want when you start referencing multiple bits of geometry, because there's more potential for self-intersection on the target.

Another way to do this would be to use a proxy object.  We could use geometry nodes, or a boolean-union that referenced a collection, to make an object that represented multiple objects:

[image]

Here, I'm booleaning a point with a collection, giving me a single object I can use as the target of a shrinkwrap.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question used the phrase "more than one *mesh*" the answer for the shrinkwrap *modifier* is "yes, but only if the multiple meshes are contained in the same *object*.

The shrinkwrap *modifier* takes a single target *object*, so there is no way to apply it to multiple meshes if each mesh is in a separate object, but if you join the meshes into a single object you can do something like this:

[image: ugly shrinkwrap]

where Suzanne and the default cube have joined into a single object.  But no, you couldn't wrap the plane around Suzanne and a cube if they're separate objects.

You can accomplish the shrinkwrap effect without the modifier by using geometry nodes in various ways.  For examples, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251374/42221)